# android google map changeing on the run

Tags: android, google-maps

i have a map view using google map API

in my map i have few overlays markers which i've designed throw extending the  ItemizedOverlay.

i want to change this markers drawable image after the map is already visible to user.
is it possible ?

my intention is to run some lazy drawable loading (like you do in a list view), because all my images are coming from the web, and i don't want the user to wait for all the images to load before i load the map.

on a list view its kind of easy, because the thread will update the ImageView, but here i don't know how to access a specific item after the map has loaded..

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the function setMarker in OverlayItem.  It will let you change the image for a specific marker.  Just make sure you centerBound the image before setting it.

[OverLayItem](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/OverlayItem.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to me first load all the dummy iamges and show it on the mapview and simultaniously start a background task to download all the images from server and once the image downloads process completes just clear all the overlays on the mapview and reload the actually downloaded images on the mapview.

Comment: I am running into the exact same issue. Your way looks work. However, I tried with calling `setMarker()` in `Overlay.onTap()`, it does change the marker, but doesn't work in background worker, even I put it to main thread. It's very confusing about the MapView lifecycle.

Comment: also call mapview.invalidate()